# Ext.form.field.Number - formatting the value

Tags: extjs, spinner, ordinal

I have an Ext.form.field.Number where I can insert a number or use the spinner to select one.

How do I format this value for display in the Ext.form.field.Number field?

Let's say I want to have displayed, when you spin up or down:

```
1st
2nd
3rd
...
```

or

```
one
two
three
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe,  Extjs supporting  ordinal number only for date

[Please Refer Here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-getSuffix)

You can use this function to achieve that

```
    function getGetOrdinal(n) {
   var s=["th","st","nd","rd"],
       v=n%100;
   return n+(s[(v-20)%10]||s[v]||s[0]);
}
```